Kafka broker down
We are experencing the following scenario:

We have a simple kafka producer application which reads from rabbitmq and using kafka template produces messages on a kafka topic.
Our kafka producer can no longer deliver messages to the Kafka brokers when one of the brokers goes down for any reason.
Assumption: You would then expect the producer to deliver to another broker (we have 5 in the cluster).
Above does not work. The producer keeps waiting for the broker to come back. So far, we have noticed that a new broker has returned, but the connection was not restored. To resolve this, we have to manually restart the producer application.

We are using springboot 2.7.13
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Andy

Does your topic only have one partition on that down broker?

Thanks for the response, no, we don't have just one partition for this topic, however there are cdc topics in our application. Do we need to take extra consideration for cdc topic i.e topics with just one partition ?

Not sure what you mean by "I.e." here. Does it have one partition? Kafka itself doesn't care if CDC is used. One partition with one replica only exists on one broker... If that broker is down, you won't be able to read or produce to that partition/broker

"i.e." stands for that is. Topic in question here doesn't have a single partition. On further searching, I came across this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/discussions/2250. What do you think ?

Adminclient can be used for connectivity checking, sure. But if multiple replicas are available on different brokers for the topic in question, then Kafka should elect new leader partitions, then the producer should be able to send messages to the other brokers

You have a point there, I am assuming the same.  You would then expect the producer to deliver to another broker (we have 5 in the cluster). I would keep looking, if there is any tips or direction you can point me in then please do share.

Number of brokers doesn't matter if there is only one replica of a particular partition, placed on the down broker. Use kafka-topics --describe to check it
